# What does the latin letter mean in Bayer name of a star such as "$\Upsilon$ Andromedae $b$"?

Tags: astronomy, conventions

What does the latin letter mean in Bayer name of a star such as the "$b$" in "$\Upsilon$ Andromedae $b$"?  I tried in vain to look it up in Wikipedia or elsewhere on the Web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indicates that it's the second star in a multiple star system.

Comment: So $\Upsilon$ Andromedae is a multiple star system?

Comment: [That is correct.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsilon_Andromedae)